# Open keyboard without clicking on TextField on tvOS - Swift

Tags: swift, keyboard, tvos

I'm creating an app and I need to login to it and I don't want to use 2 Text Field for insert Email and Password. What I would wish to achieve is: click on the button "Log in", then it will open the classic full screen keyboard that is usually appearing when you are doing click on UITextField in tvOS.

Can someone please write an example of code on how to invoke the keyboard clicking on a UIButton instead of UITextField? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So how user looks what they are typing?

Comment: That’s a good question that I would wish to ask to our UX Designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your UI is questionable, once your first text field finishes editing, you could start the other one.
Set the first text field UITextFieldDelegate to the view controller, and then:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var tf2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf1: UITextField!

    @IBAction func click() {
        tf1.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if (textField == tf1){
            tf2.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yep I had the same idea but with one difference. To use func textFieldShouldReturn for move from one text field to another one

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `UITextField` to open up the keyboard without the user having to tap on it, you can use `yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`.
I don't think you can present the keyboard without any associated input view

Comment: I think I'll just create to invisible text fields, and once the button is pushed it's calling textfield.becomeFirstResponder().